# vscode not working with spring boot with groovy

Tags: spring-boot, groovy

Setting up a new spring boot project thusly:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot

and using the spring initializer to create a simple spring boot project with java 17, Gradle and groovy, its not possible to run the resultant project with F5 or by hitting the run icon next to the app in spring boot dashboard.  The former gives:

```
You don't have an extension for debugging Groovy. Should we find a Groovy extension in the Marketplace?
```

The later gives:

```
No main class is found.
```

The main class is the only class in the project:

src/main/groovy/com/myorg/myapp/myappApplication.groovy.

Is it that vscode and its spring boot tools dont work with groovy?

I tried changing the main file from .groovy to .java (as it is 100% java), but this didn't help (same errors).

In desperation, i opened the project in intellij (free version) and it gives this error:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'myapp'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.5.
> Required by:
> project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.1.5

Interestingly, I realised I didnt have gradle installed, so i installed it, then restarted VSCode. But its giving the same errors, implying its not even trying to build anything via gradle.